# Enabling TLS Extension for Token Binding Protocol Negotiation with Java/SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, tls1.2, tls1.3

In my SpringBoot web application, I want to be able to determine whether the TLS '**token_binding**' **extension** ([RFC8472](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8472)) was used during the 'client hello-server hello' TLS negotiation procedure.

From the SpringBoot point of view, I'm pretty sure that I have to override the restTemplate using my custom SSLSocketFactory instance, similar to this one: [Spring Boot AsyncRestTemplate SSLSocketFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35270709/spring-boot-asyncresttemplate-sslsocketfactory)

However, I have no clue **how to read/obtain token_binding extension** out of this. It would appreciate an example of how to extract this, or at least how to add any extension to TLS/SSL structure using java (for SSL client).

Answer (score 0):

Java does not make it easy to access the stuff from the TLS layer that you'd need. I did some related work that you can see at https://github.com/pingidentity/java8-token-binding-negotiation but stopped maintaining it after Chrome removed its token binding support (https://identiverse.com/2018/10/31/chrome-puts-token-binding-in-a-bind/ has a little more color on all that).

Answer (score 0):

The Java TLS APIs needs to add support for this. OpenJDK has an open issue to add support for this https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8236511. However, the comment from the Java SSE maintainer states.

> Changing fixVersion from "16" to "tbd". Although token binding seems
> like an important feature that we may want to support, the standards
> in this area are still somewhat in flux. RFC 8472 is not widely
> supported by browsers/TLS toolkits and is considered controversial by
> some. A different solution using TLS mutual authentication may be a
> better approach: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8705/
>
> We feel that we should wait for now to see how this area plays out.